# Wordpress error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, errors

Hell, I have an error:

> > Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /home4/smakolyk/public_html/pcwordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/importers/class-wc-product-csv-importer-controller.php:85

Error shows only with ajax request.
I fixed errors: ABSPATH AND WC_ABSPATH not defined and there is a problem with these.

I enqued script and still the same error.

It seems like ajxurl does not see includes

Comment: You should include code if you want assistance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @TonyDjukic , I included settings.php and it works